# YII framework user friendly URL

Tags: php, yii

My yii PHP project has  *UserController* and it has an action called *actionView*. I can access user view page using following URL

```
mysite.com/user/view/id/1
```

I want to change that one to

```
mysite.com/username
```

How Can I do it.

I know that i can simply create rule to be more user friendly to get url such as

```
mysite.com/user/username
```

But url scheme with database resource name as direct param (`mysite.com/username`) is whole different story.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url "2. User-friendly URLs "

Comment: While this looks like duplicate, case when only parameter is used as url is a bit different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Url rule:

```
array(
    '<username:\w+>'=>'user/view',
)
```

Note that in such scheme, you must also create rules for all your controllers and place above rule at the end, so better prefix it with user:

```
array(
    'user/<username:\w+>'=>'user/view',
)
```

Resulting url will be `example.com/user/username`

In action:

```
public function actionView($username) ...
```

**Update:**
To make rule which reacts on any input variable create custom url rule class, here is some example, modify to your needs:

```
class PageUrlRule extends CBaseUrlRule
{

        public function createUrl($manager, $route, $params, $ampersand)
        {
                // Ignore this rule for creating urls
                return false;
        }

        public function parseUrl($manager, $request, $pathInfo, $rawPathInfo)
        {
                // Ignore / url or any controller name - which could conflict with username
                if($pathInfo == '/')
                {
                        return true;
                }
                // Search for username or any resource in db
                // This is for mongo so it should be tuned to your db,
                // just check if username exists
                $criteria = new EMongoCriteria();
                $criteria->url->$lang = $url;
                $criteria->select(['_id']);
                $criteria->limit(1);
                $model = PageItem::model();
                $cursor = $model->findAll($criteria);
                // Create route, instead of $url id can be used
                $route = sprintf('content/page/view/url/%s', urlencode($url));
                // If found return route or false if not found
                return $cursor->count() ? $route : false;
        }

}
```

Then place this rule in beginning of urlmanager config

```
'rules' => [
    [
        'class' => 'application.modules.content.components.PageUrlRule'
    ],
    // Other rules here
```

**Important**: If user has username same as your controller, it will match username and controller will be inaccessible. You must forbid registering users with same names as controllers.

Comment: `example.com/user/username` is not the thing I looked for.I want to remove user part.
I want `example.com/username`.

Comment: It's best to create custo url rule class, i'll post it later, I have something similar that somewhere