# How to Rewrite hardcoded url in yii?

Tags: url, yii, url-rewriting, hardcoded

How to Rewrite hardcoded url in yii?

I have made a url as follows,

```
CHtml::link($visit->health_institute_name, array('hospitals_single', 'id'=>$visit->health_institute_id));
```

It redireceted to the url as follow,
http://abc.com/hospital?name=yyy&id=14#ad-image-0
 I Just want the url to be as follows,
http://abc.com/yyy

ie: i need to remove hospital?name= and &id=14#ad-image-0 from the url...

Can any one help?

Comment: Add rules to urlManager in main.php, http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url checkout this url.

Comment: This kind of urls (http://example.com/some-name-from-db) are a bit different, see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025630/yii-framework-user-friendly-url/19027460#19027460

Answer (score 1):

In your urlManager rules, add this after all other rules:

```
'<name>' => 'hospital/view',
```

assuming `view` is the action you want to call - replace it with your action name

Then your link as follows:

```
CHtml::link($visit->health_institute_name, Yii::app()->getBaseUrl(true).'/'.$visit->name);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make a user friendly and seo-friendly like **http://abc.com/hospital/yyy**

You can use this:

```
class CarUrlRule extends CBaseUrlRule
{
    public $connectionID = 'db';

    public function createUrl($manager,$route,$params,$ampersand)
    {
        if ($route==='car/index')
        {
            if (isset($params['manufacturer'], $params['model']))
                return $params['manufacturer'] . '/' . $params['model'];
            else if (isset($params['manufacturer']))
                return $params['manufacturer'];
        }
        return false;  // this rule does not apply
    }

    public function parseUrl($manager,$request,$pathInfo,$rawPathInfo)
    {
        if (preg_match('%^(\w+)(/(\w+))?$%', $pathInfo, $matches))
        {
            // check $matches[1] and $matches[3] to see
            // if they match a manufacturer and a model in the database
            // If so, set $_GET['manufacturer'] and/or $_GET['model']
            // and return 'car/index'
        }
        return false;  // this rule does not apply
    }
}
```

More informatino there !
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/fr/topics.url#using-custom-url-rule-classes